# How to cast double value to first characters

Tags: math, double

Hello brothers I have work for along time to show the first 6 character from double value so I couldn't do that and I need a simple method, Ex:

Here's my double value I need to cast it: 14.7534343267653.

I need to show the first 7 characters only: 14.7534.

So any body can solve this with a simple way.

Comment: You need proper formatting, so refer to Format/printf etc specifiers for your language.

Comment: But can you give me fully correct answer.

Comment: Correct answer is using formatting functions.

Comment: The complete answer is language-specific, so you'd need to add a language tag.  Most languages have formatting functions and/or rounding functions to truncate/round to a set number of decimal points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example of doing what you are looking for in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double number = 14.7534343267653;
    printf("%2.4f", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Other languages have identical or very similar **format specifiers**, so esentially `"%2.4f"` and some string `format()` might be what you are looking for.